# JUJU : error: error parsing environment "amazon": no public ssh keys found

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

help me please! I tried to configure the enviroments.yaml and set the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` then `juju bootstrap`.. I have this:

> error: error parsing environment "amazon": no public ssh keys found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Generate public/private keys with:

> ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048

- key name must be "id_rsa"
- Save file "id_rsa.pub" in ~/.ssh
- Try again.

Comment: Hey @malvakian, I'm trying to get this setup to work as well. I've made sure that the ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub file exists, and I'm still getting the same error that OP was getting. Any thoughts?